# how generate logs and reports in ruby capybara rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, report, capybara

I am new to this technology and I am working on an automation framework, ruby-capybara-rspec. And this project is in POC state. Now I want to generate "Logs" and "reports" as well. Please help me if there is any default/inbuilt functionality to do so or is there any specific gem I can use to achieve it. Thank you in advance.

PS: There is no specific ask from the client so I can bring my own logging and report to this framework.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: rspec can generate pretty(ish) html reports you can redirect to a file in your public/ dir for example. Capybara can also generate screenshots of your failing examples and store them in another directory with indexing enabled on web server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format-saved-to-a-file) documentation:

```
rspec example_spec.rb --format documentation --out rspec.txt
```

Comment: It works, but UI of text is not that good, I tried HTML that works much better. Could you please help me with logs also?